# Fragment displays on the whole screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragment displays on the whole screen even if FrameLayout height and width are set in Dp

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27
```

**activity_main2.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main2Activity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/></RelativeLayout>
```

**Before Fragment insert:**

[image: Before Fragment insert]

**After Fragment insert:**

[image: After Fragment insert]

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/opacity" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="home" /></LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(android.R.id.content, new HomeFragment(),HomeFragment.HOME_FRAGMENT_TAG)
    .addToBackStack("Home")
    .commit();
```

Please, does anybody know how to set fragment like this:

[image: how to set fragment like that]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the fragment is occupying whole screen including actionbar, then you will need to add another xml name it **content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.digiclack.videostatus.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

then in app_bar_main.xml remove FrameLayout tag and add

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

**now refer it this way**

```
.replace(R.id.frag_container, new HomeFragment(),HomeFragment.HOME_FRAGMENT_TAG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file is okay just add the background color.

android:background="#FF69B4" on FrameLayout

```
        android:layout_width="300dp"

        android:layout_height="300dp"

        android:background="#FF69B4"
        >

    </FrameLayout>
```